# Kibana is not accessible from external browser

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, port, kibana, elastic-stack

I am trying to install Elasticsearch and Kibana on Debian 10.  they both work and active in the current machine. I want to access Kibana through different machine's browser, but it cannot be reached.

I have changed Kibana.yml configuration,

```
server.port: 5601
server.host: "IP" - my IP address
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://IP:9200"]
```

Also, I have enabled 5601 and 9200 ports through he firewall by using UFW commands.

even though, still not working. Any idea how to fix that??

Thanks,
almo

Comment: Can you do a traceroute on the ip and port from the host which you are trying to use as the request from? This might give you insight of where it is getting blocked (or routed wrong)

Comment: Run `netstat -na | grep 5601` to see what’s in LISTEN state on the local machine

Comment: I have already tried that, it shows I am using 5601 port for only the ip I specified. Also, I have tried 0.0.0.0 as a server.host, but still no luck.